# Can not find object file with cmake link_directories

Tags: object, gcc, cmake, ld

I want to add several .o files to the link process. If I do it like this:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(FFMPEGTest stdc++fs -pthread /home/stiv2/jsoft/nv-ffmpeg/ffmpeg/libswresample/audioconvert.o ...some more stuff... )
```

then it finds the file. All of these files are in the same directory, so I want to add them semultaneously:

```
link_directories(/home/stiv2/jsoft/nv-ffmpeg/ffmpeg/libswresample/)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(FFMPEGTest stdc++fs -pthread audioconvert.o ...some more stuff... )
```

but this doesn't work:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -laudioconvert.o
```

how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/target_link_libraries.html) for `target_link_libraries` doesn't allow a **relative path** (`audioconvert.o`) to be a parameter to that command. It should be either **absolute path** (`/home/stiv2/jsoft/nv-ffmpeg/ffmpeg/libswresample/audioconvert.o`) or a **plain library name** (like `z` for `libz.a` library).

Because the object file `audioconvert.o` is not a library, it cannot be specified with a *plain library name*. You have no other choice than specify an **absolute path** for the object files.

For specify several object files in some directory you may use `foreach` loop:

```
foreach(obj audioconvert.o foo.o bar.o)
  target_link_libraries(FFMPEGTest /home/stiv2/jsoft/nv-ffmpeg/ffmpeg/libswresample/${obj})
endforeach()
```

---

Actually, every parameter `<param>` to `target_link_libraries`, which doesn't look like an absolute path (and doesn't corresponds to a library *target*), is transformed into `-l<param>` option for the linker.

The linker interprets this parameter as a *plain library name*, and [searches](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Link-Options.html) for a file named `lib<param>.a` or `lib<param>.so` in the link directories.

So, with parameter `-laudioconvert.o` the linker searches a file with a name `libaudioconvert.o.a` - obviously, this is not what do you want.